# How can I write a function in the same way they are written in standard library?

Tags: r

EDIT: although this question will be relevant to many statistics students (especially ones with experience with other programming languages), it has been closed. The hint given was very helpful, though. You can use the ifelse function as shown below:

```
qbern24 <- function(x, p) {
        ifelse(x <= 0, -Inf,
               ifelse(x > 0 & x <= 1-p, 0,
                  ifelse(x > 1-p & x <= 1, 1,
                     Inf)
                  )
               )
}
```

If you want to vectorize something else, I wish you luck.

/EDIT

The functions in the standard library will take "numeric vectors" and return numeric vectors but mine don't. How can i write qbern04 so that I can use it in the same way as qnorm, without having to use as.numeric and lapply?

```
    qbern <- function(x, p) {
            if (x <= 0) {
                    -Inf
            } else if (x > 0 & x <= 1-p) {
                    0
            } else if (x > 1-p & x <= 1) {
                    1
            } else {
                    Inf
            }
    }


    qbern04 <- function(x) {
                    qbern(x, 0.4)
    }

    U <- runif(1e6)
    X <- as.numeric(lapply(U, qbern04))
    Z <- qnorm(U)
```

Comment: Vectorize your function, see `?vector`, `?\`[\``, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qbern <- function(x, p) {
  OTHERWISE <- TRUE
  dplyr::case_when(
                     (x <= 0) ~ -Inf,
    ((x > 0) && (x <= (1-p))) ~ 0,
      ((x > 1-p) && (x <= 1)) ~ 1,
                    OTHERWISE ~ Inf
  )
}

qbern04 <- function(x) { qbern(x, 0.4) }
```

`case_when()` is from `dplyr`. If you don't want that dependency, then read up on vectorization and learn to use `ifelse()`, `sapply()` and `vapply()` since `lapply()` is designed to return `list`s.